# Kotlin Gradle plugin: apiVersion vs languageVersion

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Kotlin Gradle plugin contains `compileKotlin` task which can be configured by `apiVersion` and `languageVersion` parameters ([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-common-for-jvm-and-js)):

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        languageVersion = '1.1'
        apiVersion = '1.1'
    }
}
```

Both parameters are used for compatibility with older Kotlin versions. Could somebody explain what is the difference between them? And what are use cases using each of them?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/compatibility-modes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apiVersion: Allow to use declarations only from the specified version of bundled libraries

languageVersion: Provide source compatibility with specified language version

You can see full documentation here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

and this reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html

Comment: Yes, this link is in my question. Could you please give an example when I should use one and when another?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't give any example. But, maybe you can found your answer by reading this reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html

Comment: Thanks! Please add a link to `Language settings` block in the last document, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: I have found the answer in your last link. Please replace link in your answer by this one: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#language-settings