# Build config for developing a Gradle Plugin written in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to build a Gradle plugin written in Kotlin and publish it to the Gradle Plugin Portal. However, I am not clear about what build config I need to achieve this. There is a lot of confusing information, and strange errors regarding the 'embedded Kotlin' that Gradle uses.

[The plugin development guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) doesn’t any examples for a Kotlin + `build.gradle.kts` (only a [simple one](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) that uses `java-gradle-plugin`)

There’s [some technical details about the embedded Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin), but it’s not clear about explicit requirements, and is more abstract technical implementation than a practical “how to” guide.

Using `gradle init` (v8.0.2) creates a project that has the Kotlin version manually set, so it might not match the embedded Kotlin version

```kotlin
// generated by `gradle init` command

plugins {
    // Apply the Java Gradle plugin development plugin to add support for developing Gradle plugins
    `java-gradle-plugin`

    // Apply the Kotlin JVM plugin to add support for Kotlin.
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.10"
}
```

What config should I use to build a Gradle plugin written in Kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, these are the best-practice rules for configuring a Gradle Project that will build a Gradle Plugin written in Kotlin.

First, note the markers † and ‡

- ‡ - these rules are automatically configured if the `kotlin-dsl` plugin is applied
- **MAY**† - this is allowed, but strongly discouraged. Bypassing this rule might seem fine, but might cause unforeseen compatibility issues with Gradle versions or features, or other plugins

### Gradle Plugin development with Kotlin - best practice rules

- **MUST** only use these combinations of plugins:

  - [The Kotlin DSL Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin), which also applies the `java-gradle-plugin` and `embedded-kotlin` plugin automatically.

    ```kotlin
    plugins {
      `kotlin-dsl`
    }
    ```
  - [The Gradle Plugin Development Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html) and [`embedded-kotlin`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gradle.kotlin.embedded-kotlin) (which is not documented)

    ```kotlin
    plugins {
      `java-gradle-plugin`
      `embedded-kotlin`
    }
    ```
  - [The Gradle Plugin Development Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html) and the [Kotlin Gradle Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html) (but note the version restrictions below, and be aware that the Kotlin Gradle Plugin automatically exposes incompatible dependencies (again, see below))

    ```kotlin
    plugins {
      `java-gradle-plugin`
      // valid, but be aware of exposing incomatible dependencies
      kotlin("jvm") version embeddedKotlinVersion
    }
    ```
- **MUST NOT** use `kotlin("jvm")` with `embedded-kotlin` OR `kotlin-dsl`

  ```kotlin
  // ❌ invalid example
  plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    // don't specify two different Kotlin plugins
    `embedded-kotlin`
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10"
  }
  ```
- **MAY**† use any version of `kotlin("jvm")`, but SHOULD use the same version as is used by Gradle. There's a helper variable, [`embeddedKotlinVersion`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0fdf6a858330e11c3b50ce769e38578d9e2e8c86/build-logic/kotlin-dsl/src/main/kotlin/gradlebuild/kotlindsl/generator/tasks/GenerateKotlinDependencyExtensions.kt#L70-L73), that will provide this automatically.

  ```kotlin
  plugins {
     `java-gradle-plugin`
     kotlin("jvm") version embeddedKotlinVersion
  }
  ```
- ‡ **MUST** set the [Kotlin language level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55000046/4161471) appropriately, following the [Gradle compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#kotlin)

  ```kotlin
  // assume that the current Gradle version is 7.6

  plugins {
     `java-gradle-plugin`
     `embedded-kotlin`
  }

  tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
     kotlinOptions {
       apiVersion = "1.4"
       languageVersion = "1.4"
     }
  }
  ```
- **MUST NOT** use add `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` or `kotlin-reflect` Kotlin libraries, or `gradleKotlinDsl()` as runtime/implementation dependencies, as they will conflict with Gradle’s embedded versions, and potentially with other Gradle plugins.
- ‡ **SHOULD**† use `compileOnly()` dependencies on `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`, `kotlin-reflect`, and `gradleKotlinDsl()` with a version equal to `embeddedKotlinVersion`
- ‡ **MUST** use `compileOnly(gradleApi())` (the version defaults to the version of Gradle being used to build the project) **MAY**† not match the Gradle versions that you want the plugin to support.
- ‡ **MUST** add [Kotlin compiler arguments](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin_compiler_arguments) `-java-parameters -Xjvm-default=all -Xsam-conversions=class Xjsr305=strict` for compatibility with Config Cache, and improved interoperability with Java and Groovy
- **SHOULD** use Gradle's [Plugin Publishing plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/docs/publish-plugin) to publish plugins to the Gradle Plugin Portal.

#### An example `build.gradle.kts`

Since most options are configured by the `kotlin-dsl` plugin, that provides the simplest method for building a Gradle plugin written in Kotlin.

1. Create a project using a Gradle version that best matches the Gradle versions you want to support, since the Gradle version being used to build the plugin will provide most defaults.

   (While it is possible to create [variants of Gradle plugins per Gradle version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#plugin-with-variants), this is *very* complicated and not well supported by the Gradle API)
2. Create a `build.gradle.kts` with the following config:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
  id("com.gradle.plugin-publish") version "$gradlePluginPublishVersion"
}

// Optional: enable stricter validation, to ensure Gradle configuration is correct
tasks.validatePlugins {
  enableStricterValidation.set(true)
}

// create the plugin
// Read more: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/implementing_gradle_plugins.html#plugin-development-plugin
gradlePlugin {
  plugins {
    create("simplePlugin") {
      id = "org.example.greeting"
      implementationClass = "org.example.GreetingPlugin"
    }
  }
}
```